# How to take multiple VLC snapshot into specific folder

Tags: python, png, vlc, snapshot

This code is working well, but it keep replacing the previous snapshot in the location I dont want.
How can I keep taking the snapshot every second without replacing the previous shot, and how can I specify the folder for these png going to be saved?

```
player=vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://admin:888999@thesport.fujiko.biz:554/unicast/c3/s0/live')
player.play()

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, '.snapshot.tmp.png', 0, 0)
```

Comment: You change the filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, every time you get a frame, store it in different variable, like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the one comment says, you need to change the filename for each subsequent save. I would create a count in your loop and then format the value to the string that is the filename. For example:

```
player=vlc.MediaPlayer('rtsp://admin:888999@thesport.fujiko.biz:554/unicast/c3/s0/live')
player.play()

i = 0

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    player.video_take_snapshot(0, '.snapshot_{}.tmp.png'.format(i), 0, 0)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply specify a directory name, rather than a filename, `vlc` will create a unique file name for you, based on the date and time.

i.e.
file:///home/rolf/vlcsnap-2020-08-14-10h43m06s020.png
file:///home/rolf/vlcsnap-2020-08-14-10h43m08s936.png

```
#Video Snapshot
def OnSnapShot(self,evt):
    media_state = self.player.get_state()
    if media_state.value < 3 or media_state.value > 4:
        return
    if os.path.isfile(self.currentlyplaying):
        dir_name = os.path.dirname(self.currentlyplaying)
    else:
        dir_name = self.home_dir
    snapshot_size = self.player.video_get_size(0)
    x=self.player.video_take_snapshot(0, dir_name,snapshot_size[0],snapshot_size[1])
    if x == 0:
        Notify(self,"Snapshot","Image saved in "+dir_name)
```